# TCP on the same (server side) source port to multiple (different destinations)?

Tags: tcp

**Question 2**
Is it true that a TCP server may send segments with the same (server side) source port to multiple (different destinations)?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. That's how servers handle multiple clients with a single, well-known port.